# Inject CSS into existing website with no ftp access and use live reload

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-devtools

A client of ours provided us with an existing website which we have to restyle. Problem is, we have no ability to upload our css file and the client is not giving us access to her webserver. Thus, we have to send her the final css which will then be included.

**Current workflow**

scss file > gulp watch > insert css into  of website via javascript in the developer tools of chrome

Live reloading the css is not working with this setup and I'm wondering if there's a better solution to style an existing website to which a developer has no access.

Comment: Excuse my stupid question, but why don't you grab the website into your development setup, do your thing and then hand over your results?

Comment: What about saving a copy of the file locally with all of the current assets, and then creating your css on top of that?

Comment: Yes, I grabbed the website with wget but for some reason all angular directives are showing up as plain text, e.g. {{customer}}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try https://github.com/One-com/livestyle

We built it for this exact purpose. It injects the livereload client script into any html that passes through the server, so you don't need to handle that. It also has the ability to compile sass, as you are doing, and serve css from your local file system while proxying anything else to the remote server.

The command line you need is something like this: `livestyle -r path/to/webroot --proxy http://clientwebsite.com --compilesass --autoprefixer`

This will work if the file paths in your local web root are a mirror of the remote css files. If you need a more involved setup, you might need to dive into mapping directories specificly: https://github.com/One-com/livestyle#--map-m-sourcepathprefixtargetpathprefix

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. It works on all kinds of websites, except the one from our client. This is the debugging output:

`Proxying / to http://tibp.cloudapp.net/ => 404
GET / 404 207.836 ms - -`

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Looks like that page is behind a login form, which might cause some trouble. Try adding the `--debug` flag to pump up the logging to maximum. Then you might be able to spot what's going on

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to use UserScripts.
If you read into [userscripts](http://userscripts-mirror.org/) this is entirely possible using a bit of JavaScript to inject say a reset css file and then your custom css to websites you define.

The [Stylish extension](http://userstyles.org) for Firefox also allows this. I don't know if there's a similar capability in IE.

Here's the [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) to the Stylish extension for chrome.

Another option is to save the entire website to your pc, then host it yourself in a local environment and edit the css.
When you're statisfied you can just send the css to your client and he/she can upload it to the webserver.